# How to disable the button having similar Id using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the 3 buttons id's like `#button1,#button2,#button3`.Now I click `#button2`,here i want to disable the other 2 buttons that is `#button1,#button3`.We can use `$("#myButton").attr("disabled", true);` to disable the button.But here we should have some logic on this.  Kindly help me.

Comment: You could use a class selector to get all buttons of a kind, then iterate and disable each one by one.

Comment: You are looking for a logic which will disable the other buttons while clicking on one button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all three elements and remove the currently clicked one:

```
$('#button1,#button2,#button3').click(function(){
  $('#button1,#button2,#button3').not(this).attr('disabled',true);
});
```

#### Edit:

You can also use a variable to reduce the repetition, both in the code and the exectution:

```
var buttons = $('#button1,#button2,#button3');
buttons.click(function(){
  buttons.not(this).attr('disabled',true);
});
```

You might also consider using a class on the buttons instead of specifing each id, that generally makes it easier to maintain:

```
var buttons = $('.Radio-ish-button');
buttons.click(function(){
  buttons.not(this).attr('disabled',true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {

  $('#button2').live('click', function () {
    $('#button1,#button3').attr('disabled', true);
  });

});
```

**EDIT:**  after comments, try to use classes instead of id's

```
$(function () {

  $('.buttons').live('click', function () {
    $('.buttons').not(this).attr('disabled', true);
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks,here buttons will be dynamically generated,i can pass the button id when user onclick, but other buttons except clicked button should get disabled. Hope you understand

Comment: try to stick to classes instead of id's

Comment: Fixed the spelling "dissabled" and a missing comma in the selector. :)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$("input[id^=button]").click(function(){
    $("input[id^=button]").not(this).attr('disabled',true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by filtering the pressed button out from the tree button set.

we can use `not` on the list to filter out the button pressed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button1,#button2,#button3').click(function() {
        $('#button1,#button2,#button3').not(this).attr('disabled',true)
    });
});
```